# WP Custom permalinks convert /store/page/3/ to /store/?paged=3

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I would like to know if there is a way to convert the following structure link:

> https://example.com/store/page/3/

To

> https://example.com/store/?paged=3

Plain permalinks wouldn't work because it will turn the link into https://example.com/?post_id=idStorePage&paged=3

So, I would like to keep pages like store and checkout between /%postname%/ but paged and categories as parameters of the url ?paged=3&category=example

Comment: The request is a bit weird. Do you want to expand on what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @Kevin, Can you please mention some more details?